# How do I get a value from an Object that is an array?

Tags: java, object

I have an Object:

```
Object o = new Object[] {0, "key", 1234, "name"};
```

How can get specify data from it?

Like:

```
o[2] //1234
```

or

```
o[1] //"key"
```

Eclipse gives the error:

`The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object.`

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have an array of random objects? I've never found it necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `o` like this:

```
Object [] o = {0, "key", 1234, "name"};
```

You can then access it as you specified.

Answer (score 0):

You may define it as an array:
`Object[] o = new Object[] {0, "key", 1234, "name"};`